# Showing $\{f(\frac{1}{n+1})\}$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-verification, cauchy-sequences, lipschitz-functions

Question: Let $f:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $|f'(x)| \leq 5$, for all $x \in (0,1)$. Show that the sequence $\{f(\frac{1}{n+1})\}$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$.

Attempt:

Consider any $a, b$ such that $[a,b] \subset (0,1)$. By LMVT  $|\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}| \leq 5$ $\implies |f(b)-f(a)|\leq 5|b-a|$.

The sequence $\{\frac{1}{n+1}$} converges. Hence, by Cauchy's General Principle, $\forall \epsilon >0$, $\exists \ N>0$ such that $|\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{m+1}| < \epsilon/5$ for every $m, n >N$.

Hence, $ |f(\frac{1}{n+1})-f(\frac{1}{m+1})|\leq 5|\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{m+1}|< \epsilon$, whenever  $m, n >N$.

PS: Please do check the solution thoroughly. Kindly correct any "false assumptions", "weak -wordings", "misplaced predicates" etc. A little help goes a long way. I am struggling with proper proof writing right now.

Comment: Your answer is Correct.

Comment: Looks fine to.me.

Answer (score 2):

An other approach.

$$(\forall x\in (0,1)) \; |f'(x)|\le 5 \implies $$

$$f \text{ is Uniformly continuous at } (0,1) \implies $$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x) \text{ exists in } \Bbb R \implies$$

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}f(\frac{1}{n+1})\in \Bbb R.$$

PS

I know that tomorrow my total points will decrease with NO reason. should i change my name.

Comment: hamam.Please elaborate.f uniformly continuous in (0,1) implies $ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x) in R exists.Thanks.

Comment: C'est le théorème du prolongement des fonctions uniformément continues.

Comment: hamam.Merci bien., Peter